# Will A/B testing(using google optimize) give the same result for a specific user during the experiment?

Tags: angular, abtest

I am setting up A/B testing for one of my angular single page application. During the experiment, if a user clears the cookies, will he/she view the original website or the different version of the website?

In short, will the user see the same experience if he/she clears the cookies and refreshes the page?

Answer (score 0):

if a user clears the cookies Optimize will reassign them a variant, it may be the original or not. Optimize relies on the _gaexp cookie to know if the user has already been in the experiment before and assign the same version to him/her, if the cookie is deleted Optimize cannot know.